My radiobutton is not working as intended
I have a form component that utilizes the react-hook-form to handle the form submission.However, my MUI Radio group is not properly setting the values as intended.I have two radio options, Male and Female. Currently, only the Male button works. However, If i position Female to be first, then the Female button will work.
Here is my component:
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '16px', maxWidth: '400px', margin: 'auto' }}>
   <TextField 
      {...register('name', { required: true, minLength: 6, maxLength: 10 })} 
      label="Name" 
      variant="outlined" 
      fullWidth 
   />
            
   <TextField 
       {...register('email_address', { required: true })} 
       label="Email Address" 
       variant="outlined" 
       fullWidth 
    />
            
    <TextField 
        {...register('phone_number', { required: true })} 
        label="Phone Number" 
        variant="outlined" 
        fullWidth 
     />
            
     <FormControl component="fieldset" required>
        <FormLabel>Gender</FormLabel>
           <RadioGroup {...register('gender', { required: true })}>
              <FormControlLabel value="Male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
              <FormControlLabel value="Female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
            </RadioGroup>
         </FormControl>

         <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
            <InputLabel id="cafe-select-label">Select Cafe</InputLabel>
            <Select
               labelId="cafe-select-label"
               {...register('cafe_name')}
               defaultValue=""
            >
               <MenuItem value="" disabled />
                {cafes.map(cafe => (
                    <MenuItem key={cafe.name} value={cafe.name}>{cafe.name}</MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
         </FormControl>

         <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth>
                Submit
         </Button>
        </form>

I have tried logging the form's data to see what is happening, and when I select on the top button, the value gets set as expected. When i select the second button, the value gets set to null instead.

Hi you can use watch in react-hook-form to check the value of the radio button
const { register, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm();
const selectedGender = watch('gender', '');
<FormControl component="fieldset" required>
     <FormLabel>Gender</FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup {...register('gender', { required: true })}
                value={selectedGender}>
        <FormControlLabel value="Male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
        <FormControlLabel value="Female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
          </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>


